# What to take in account when deploying complete redesign of website regarding search engines?

Tags: html, seo

I am planning redesign of my page (4-5 years old with pagerank 3-4). There will not be any URLs changing, meaning that the same content will stay under the same URL. But I am still bothered, because I heard that changing HTML structure on whole page can have some effect, mainly negative. But there is no way of changing design and layout of the page without changing HTML structure.

Could you please sum up all the things to take into account when redesigning website search-engine-friendly-way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could go into some detail but basically check your site with this to get a detailed breakdown: http://nibbler.silktide.com/ Before and your test site (Preferably on a test domain ie. **test**.mywebsite.com).

Basic things not to do are: **Do not use html tables** for anything but displaying data in a grid, do not use **semantic html** where not needed this is used to highlight things as important.

Order of importance tags on a page
H1 < H2 < H3 < B

Make sure your html is valid and you have all the appropriate meta-tags in place as per the **w3c standard** you choose for your design.

Content is key, **keyword density** and **page themes** are what are important don't dilute a page, if you are going to add a new page.

Make sure you add a **site map and submit to all search engines** and have a **robots.txt** file pointing to your local **xml sitemap**.

For everything that you didn't understand that I said google the phrases in bold and you will find more detail of implementation.

Comment: Thanks for answer, however I was looking for something more specific to transition of old web to web with new design. Your answer is mostly general to any new web.

Comment: The question is very broad, the markup comments I made are pretty much the only differences that I can think would be different due to the vast nature of differences across the web in old sites. Nibbler the link I provided will scan your old website and make a detailed analysis for you, which should be more accurate help.